# GCC+STM32: missing one element in array

Tags: gcc, stm32, eclipse-cdt

I have faced with a strange problem.
I have moved my project from Keil to STM32 IDE. (based on Eclipse and GCC).
In Keil I don't have any problems. But in Eclipse there is.
The CPU is STM32F030xC

I am defining an array of structures.

```
typedef struct
{
  int width; // Character width in bits.
  int offset; // Offset in bytes into font bitmap.
}
FONT_CHAR_INFO;
const FONT_CHAR_INFO microsoftSansSerif_18ptDescriptors[] = 
{
{2, 0},         // ! 
{6, 25},        // " 
{13, 50},       // # 
{11, 100},      // $
```

and so on. There are 94 elements.
The size of the array should be 8 * 94 = 752 bytes
But in linker map I see the size 744.
And in debugger one element is missing. With the index of 60.
The 60 index in memory points to 61 in array.
Other elements are present.

Maybe that relates somehow with data align? But the size of array should be bigger.
I am using compiler without optimization.
What is going on?

Comment: It seems highly unlikely the compiler is doing this, and more likely there's a bug in your code (or your assumptions). Can you compile a little `.c` file with just your structure definition and array, on say Linux, and see what sizes you get? Or edit your question to include the entire array, and I'll do it.

Comment: You should really edit your question to include the entire array anyway, since this seems to be where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60th element in an ASCII table starting at ! = 33, is code 93; and the one just before that with code 92 is backslash (\). The C preprocessor understands the backslash at the end of line as a continuation mark, merges that line with the subsequent line, and as you have a line comment mark (//) just before that, the whole combined line is removed as a comment.

Don't put backslash at the end of line.

Comment: That is exact reason!! I had {7, 2725},   // \ there. This is not my code I took it from other library. Strange but KEIL compiler does not comments it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It may have been not the *same* source being compiled by the two compilers, even if visually identical. C99 5.1.1.2#2 says, _"Each instance of a backslash character (\\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines."_ If there's a space after the backslash, you won't see it yet it would prevent from continuation. Some editors remove end-of-line spaces automatically, and then the backslash may suddenly become a continuation mark.